# Lens / Prism with error handling

Tags: scala, haskell, haskell-lens, lenses, monocle-scala

Let's say I have a pair of conversion functions

```
string2int :: String -> Maybe Int
int2string :: Int -> String
```

I could represent these fairly easily using Optics.

`stringIntPrism :: Prism String Int`

However if I want to represent failure reason, I'd need to keep these as two separate functions.

```
string2int :: String -> Validation [ParseError] Int
int2string :: Int -> String`
```

For this simple example `Maybe` is perfectly fine, since we can always assume that a failure is a parse failure, thus we don't actually have to encode this using an Either or Validation type.

However imagine, in addition to my parsing Prism, I want to perform some validation

```
isOver18 :: Int -> Validation [AgeError] Int
isUnder55 :: Int -> Validation [AgeError] Int
```

It would be ideal to be able compose these things together, such that I could have

`ageField = isUnder55 . isOver18 . string2Int :: ValidationPrism [e] String Int`

This is fairly trivial to build by hand, however it seems like a common enough concept that there might be something lurking in the field of Lenses/Optics that does this already. Is there an existing abstraction that handles this?

tl;dr

Is there a standard way of implementing a partial lens / prism / iso that can be parameterised over an arbitrary functor instead of being tied directly to Maybe?.

I've used Haskell notation above since it's more straight forward, however I'm actually using Monocle in Scala to implement this. I would, however, be perfectly happy with an answer specific to i.e. ekmett's Lens library.

Comment: I remember a reddit discussion about a similar question from some way back. In it, Edward Kmett [mentioned the notion](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/34igpj/hypothetical_lens_xml_parsing_that_documents/cqv346w) of "coindexed prisms" that would be able to report error information while remaining composable with normal lenses. Apparently, they were difficult to fit into the lens framework because of type inference issues, so they weren't implemented.

Comment: I think the concept of a Traversal would be appropriate here.

Answer (score 6):

I have recently written [a blog post](http://oleg.fi/gists/posts/2017-04-26-indexed-poptics.html#coindexed) about indexed optics; which explores a bit how we can do coindexed optics as well.

In short: Coindexed-optics are possible, but we have yet to do some further research there. Especially, because if we try to translate that approach into `lens` encoding of lenses (from Profunctor to VL) it gets even more hairy (but I think we can get away with *only* 7 type-variables).

And we **cannot** really do this without altering how indexed optics are currently encoded in `lens`. So for now, you'll better to use validation specific libraries.

To give a hint of the difficulties: When we try to compose with `Traversal`s, should we have

```
-- like `over` but also return an errors for elements not matched
validatedOver :: CoindexedOptic' s a -> (a -> a) -> s -> (ValidationErrors, s)
```

or something else? If we could only compose Coindexed Prisms their value won't justify their complexity; they won't "fit" into optics framework.